# ActionListener error when passing arrays as arguments for thread safety

Tags: java, arrays, swing, thread-safety, actionlistener

I am re-writing some code to improve thread safety.  I am trying to pass arrays as arguments rather than storing them in class variables.  But an error is being thrown where a button in my gui needs to update/reload the contents of a panel in my gui.

It looks like I need to somehow pass these arrays into the button or into ActionListener, but I do not know how to do that.  Since the problem is buried in many thousands of lines of irrelevant code, I have re-created the relevant aspects in the code sample below.  The only other problem with the code below is that for some reason it it not making the button visible.  But otherwise, the code below accurately recreates the error that is being thrown in my application.  Note that the code prints a message when the pane is reloaded with data in the two arrays.

Can anyone show me how to change the code below so that it is able to pass the arrays as arguments when the button is clicked to refresh the panel's contents?

The code is in three files as follows:

Parent.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Parent extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JLayeredPane desktop;
JInternalFrame internalFrame;

public Parent() {
    super("title goes here");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
    double[] myDBL = {2.3,5.4,6.5,7.8,2.4,6.4,9.0,5.3,8.1};
    String[] mySTR = {"ko","lp","dk"};
    Panel p = new Panel();
    this.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    this.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        int ifWidth = 600;
        int ifHeight = 300;
        internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("title", true, true, true, true);
        // create jtabbed pane
        JTabbedPane jtp = createTabbedPane(myDBL,mySTR);
        internalFrame.add(jtp);
        desktop.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setSize(new Dimension(ifWidth,ifHeight));
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
}
private JTabbedPane createTabbedPane(double[] myDBL, String[] mySTR) {
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    createTab(jtp, "Data",myDBL,mySTR);
    return jtp;
}
private void createTab(JTabbedPane jtp, String s,double[] myDBL, String[] mySTR) {
    if(s=="Data"){
        PanelGUI myTimeSeriesGUI = new PanelGUI(myDBL,mySTR);
        jtp.add(s,myTimeSeriesGUI);
    }
    else{jtp.add(s, new JLabel("TabbedPane " + s, JLabel.CENTER));}
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Parent myParentFrame = new Parent();
    myParentFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

PanelGUI.java **(THIS FILE CONTAINS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE ERROR MESSAGE IN ECLIPSE.)**

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int visiblePoints;
public int newStartingPoint;
ToolBar myToolBar;
int frameWidth = 600;
int frameHeight = 300;

public PanelGUI(double[] myDBL, String[] mySTR){
    newStartingPoint = 0;
    visiblePoints = 5000;
    addComponentsToPane(this, myDBL,mySTR);
}
public void addComponentsToPane(Container pane, double[] myDBL, String[] mySTR) {
    pane.removeAll();
    myToolBar=new ToolBar(myDBL,mySTR);
    pane.add(myToolBar);
    myToolBar.hRescaleButton.addActionListener(this);
    System.out.println("pane reloaded successfully");
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getSource()==myToolBar.hRescaleButton){
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of milliseconds shown in window : ", "Horizontal Rescale", 1);
        if(str != null) {
            int numPoints = Integer.parseInt(str);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered: "+numPoints+"ms = "+(numPoints/1000)+"sec.", "Horizontal Rescale", 1);
            this.removeAll();
            visiblePoints = numPoints;
            frameWidth = this.getWidth();
            frameHeight = this.getHeight();
            setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
            addComponentsToPane(this,myDBL,mySTR);//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
            setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
        }
        else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You pressed cancel button.","Horizontal Rescale", 1);}
    }
}
}
```

ToolBar.java

```
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class ToolBar extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2749251105543480474L;
static final private String RESET_HSCALE = "HorizontalRescale";
JButton hRescaleButton;

public ToolBar(double[] myDBL, String[] mySTR) {
    //Create the toolbar.
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    addButtons(toolBar);
    toolBar.setFloatable(false);
    toolBar.setRollover(true);
    //Lay out the main panel.
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), 40));
    add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
}
protected void addButtons(JToolBar toolBar) {
    hRescaleButton = new JButton("Reset Horizontal Scale");
    hRescaleButton.setActionCommand(RESET_HSCALE);
    hRescaleButton.setToolTipText("Reset horizontal scale.");
    toolBar.add(hRescaleButton);
}
}
```

Comment: @glowcoder, I think my reply to your comment below answers this question as well.  Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: :-) That comment was there before I compiled the code. Although for future questions, I would advise posting the compile error as well, since it won't be apparent by just inspecting the code right away. It's important to give whatever useful information you have in the post. It shows two things: first, what's going on, always useful. Second, it shows you're actively trying to solve the problem, not that you just gave up after a roadblock. :-)

Comment: I work on this all the time.  I only post when I hit a serious roadblock.  I never give up with a roadblock.  If I post, it is because I have tried many things and need a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its difficult to understand what your trying to achieve with this code. As pointed out before the compile error you are getting is because you are using a variable that isn't in scope.

As far as giving you action listener visibility to the variables with the way you have things laid out your only option is to make them instance variables in the JPanel.

However, I would consider not having JPanel implement actionListener. Instead create the listener for hRescaleButton as an anonymous inner class. This would better encapsulate your code and you wouldn't need to check the source of the event in the handler.

See the code below.

By declaring the parameters on the addComponentsToPane method final then your anonymous inner class action listener will be able to access them.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelGUI extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public int visiblePoints;
  public int newStartingPoint;
  ToolBar myToolBar;
  int frameWidth = 600;
  int frameHeight = 300;

public PanelGUI(double[] myDBL, String[] mySTR){
    newStartingPoint = 0;
    visiblePoints = 5000;
    addComponentsToPane(this, myDBL,mySTR);
}

public void addComponentsToPane(Container pane, final double[] myDBL, final String[] mySTR) {
    pane.removeAll();
    myToolBar=new ToolBar(myDBL,mySTR);
    pane.add(myToolBar);
    myToolBar.hRescaleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of milliseconds shown in window : ", "Horizontal Rescale", 1);
            if(str != null) {
                int numPoints = Integer.parseInt(str);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered: "+numPoints+"ms = "+(numPoints/1000)+"sec.", "Horizontal Rescale", 1);
                this.removeAll();
                visiblePoints = numPoints;
                frameWidth = this.getWidth();
                frameHeight = this.getHeight();
                setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
                addComponentsToPane(this,myDBL,mySTR);//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
                setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
              }
              else{
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You pressed cancel button.","Horizontal Rescale", 1);
              }
      }});
      System.out.println("pane reloaded successfully");
}
}
```

With that said, Why do you assume passing the arrays as variables instead of storing them as instance variables will do anything to improve Thread Safety? It won't. If you want to ensure Thread Safety you need to ensure the arrays can't be accessed and modified concurrently. When you pass as an argument you are only copying object references the actual array isn't copied so the code isn't anymore thread safe.

If the arrays need to be modified after they are passed in then you need to synchronize access to the array using a common lock everywhere the array is accessed. However, I'd consider copying the array so you have your own copy that you know isn't modified. Then you wouldn't need any synchronization.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to read my code, and to try to offer a solution.  I will examine your code more closely when I have a fresh perspective tomorrow.

Comment: I do think that my objective with this code has always been extremely clear: **I want the code to be very simply modified so that it can bring the variables into scope in the place where they are not in scope, in the context of the code as I wrote it.**  I do not understand why this is so hard for people to understand.  **I would very much appreciate it if you or someone else would be so kind as to show me how to bring those variables into scope in the code as I wrote it.**  The modifications should be simple; I just do not know how to make them myself.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CodeMed _I do think that my objective with this code has always been extremely clear_ obviously, we don't think so ;-) I would suggest you remove all the unrelated clutter, strip your example down to the barest minimum, until it contains nothing else but the part that gives you trouble. Plus add the exact error message.

Comment: you have 2 options to make the variables be in scope, either make the listener an inner class and declare the params as final or declare them as instance variables. I don't think either will do anything to make the code more thread safe though

Answer (score 0):

First analysis shows the following problems:

Your error is

```
$> javac Parent.java
.\PanelGUI.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable myDBL
location: class PanelGUI
            addComponentsToPane(this,myDBL,mySTR);//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
                                     ^
.\PanelGUI.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable mySTR
location: class PanelGUI
            addComponentsToPane(this,myDBL,mySTR);//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
                                           ^
2 errors
```

And those variables, myDBL and mySTR don't seem to be part of your object.

I notice that you pass them in as constructor parameters to Toolbar, but you ever actually save them in your Toolbar class, so you can't ever get them back out.

I think you need to take a step back, identify what your objectives are, and go from there.

Comment: Thank you for examining my code.  The issues you are pointing out are exactly what I am asking for help on.  I do not know how to do what you are asking while maintaining thread safety, so I was asking you for a code sample of what you suggest.  I am concerned that making them a class variable for the button class will undermine my goal of passing by arguments instead of using class variables.  Can you show me code that solves the problem you are articulating?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to put this without sounding 'holier-than-thou' - know I'm not trying to be mean... but I have no idea what your code is supposed to do. Without knowing what it's supposed to do, I wouldn't know how to fix it. That's why I say identify what your objectives are. Perhaps you could post the "thread-unsafe" code from before you fixed it and I could take a look?

Comment: the objective is to pass two arrays into an instance of an object, rather than into class variables.  I included a test that has System.out.println print something when the panel is reloaded successfully.  But the code never gets that far because the ActionPerformed method does not have access to myDBL and mySTR.  My precise and explicit question has been: how do I give ActionPerformed access to instance arrays for the specific object that is running with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a `revalidate`, that will cause the added components to not appear. Bad API design, but true. See the API docs for [Container.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29).

Also you should add the standard boilerplate for starting a Swing front end from main:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runEDT();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show me how I would change my code specifically?  I am having a hard time figuring out how to apply your suggestions.

Comment: Add the line `revalidate();` after adding and removing (not necessary if the container has not yet been shown). (I would recommend not extending `JFrame` or `JPanel`, and in general "prefer composition over inheritance". Also applies to implementing listeners, which are generally better off as (short) anonymous inner classes.)

Comment: I agreed with all described +1